# Catalyst schema trait WithCurrentUser: some objects from old, some from cloned schema

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I have a proof-of-concept app that does the following:

- In AuthTest::Schema it preloads authentication rules into an object var.
- In AuthTest::Model::DB uses WithCurrentUser trait to have the current user set on the schema object with every web request.
- On every DB query, it checks (by subclassing ResultSet) whether the current user is allowed to perform the requested action.
- In controller code, I also explicitly call `$user->isAccessAllowed()` (which chains to the internal access control check class AuthorizationResolver).

The problem is: some DB objects in the app seem to have been created via the Schema with WithCurrentUser not initialized, and some with it initialized. E.g. the `$c->user` itself seems to have been created via the Schema without the trait WithCurrentUser.

I.e. when I call `$user->isAccessAllowed()`, which in turn calls AuthorizationResolver with `$user->result_source->schema`, this schema has current_user set to `undef`. On the other hand, when AuthorizationResolver is called from within ResultSet that I have just created from `$c->model('DB::Author')`, `current_user` in the schema is correctly set to the current user.

I.e., it seems that the user object is created (by `$c->find_user` or restored from session) from the old copy of schema that doesn't contain the WithCurrentUser trait. While any new calls to `$c->model()` create objects from the new clone.

I work this around currently by explicitly supplying the AuthorizationResolver with the user object when `$user->isAllowedAccess()` is called, but clearly the whole thing may break at another place when there are two copies of the Schema object.

Ideas welcome.